# How does Google Analytics (or any other similar service) filter spam requests?

Tags: google-analytics

Websites add the script tag for GA which is all public. At the end of the processing, it is a simple HTTP request sent to GA with website tracking id, client's agent, referrer, ... .

The question is: I can easily forge all of these and send fake requests to GA which show as legitimate visits to site X. This can make the visitor count of the site change from 10 to 1000 for example. I just have to write the script and run it on one (or multiple) server(s).

How does GA detect and handle this?

Comment: Who says they do?

Comment: Well, if they don't then how can a webmaster rely on their data?

Comment: Who says you can?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about how GA filters spam requests.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I posted here as I found other GA related questions. Do you know which other community is the best place for this question?

Comment: If this is related to your own website you could ask it on [webmasters.se].  As it is currently written, it wouldn't be on-topic there because you don't say how this is related to your own website.   Including "I"m worried that spammers might pollute my site's stats." would be enough to satisfy that.

Comment: The other possibility is [webapps.se]

Comment: There are several questions on Webmasters already about GA spam that might answer your question such as [How to fight off Google Analytics referrer spammers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-google-analytics-referrer-spammers)

Comment: I'm going deep into technicalities about how it's done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70072977/plausible-analytics-events-api-prevent-manipulation/70073972#70073972 And yes, @ceejayoz is correct in terms that GA doesn't natively filter data. It's up to you to make the data reliable. And yes, referral spam is the most popular example of exploiting GA by third parties, but it's trivial to deal with and it only targets one not-so-important-really dimension.